# Saving a permanent url for an aviary saved image (using filepicker.io and aviary tool)

Tags: filepicker.io, aviary

I am trying to have a user upload a picture that has been chosen with filepicker and then edited with aviary.  I can get the new url for the image when it is saved, but I am unsure of how to get it to persist (i.e. I would like this url to remain permanent so I can save it in a database and constantly use the image).  Is there a way to do this?  Thank you for your help.  Here is my code now:

```
$(function()  {
  var a=new Aviary.Feather({

        apiKey:'##################',
        apiVersion:2,
        tools: 'all',
        initTool: 'crop',
        cropPresets: [['Square','1:1']],
        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {

            /*
            filepicker.store(newURL,{},function(new_fpfile) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(new_fpfile));

                            });
             */

            //used to store the url, but I assume this url is temporary
            $.getJSON(
                      "/aviary_store.php", // The server URL
                      { aviary_id : newURL }, // Data you want to pass to the server.
                      function(json) {

                        var aviary_url = json[0];

                      });

                 console.log(JSON.stringify(newURL));
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(imageID));
        },

        onError:function(a){},appendTo:"editpane"});filepicker.setKey(server_vars.apikey);$(".openbutton").click(function(){filepicker.pick({mimetype:'image/*'},function(b){var c=$('<img id="#editimage"/>');c.attr("src",b.url);$(".editpane").empty().append(c);a.launch({image:c[0],url:b.url});});});});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use `filepicker.storeUrl`, which will take the contents of the saved aviary image and download it for permanent storage on your S3

Comment: how do I pull the file from S3 and have it associated with a specific user?

Comment: I tried using fielpicker.storeUrl within onSave and used newURL as the passed variable.  This didn't work, the filepicker did not open.  Any ideas?

Comment: filepicker.storeUrl will save the file to your S3, if you want to allow the user to export it to their cloud storage use filepicker.export

Comment: is it free or do we need a special account?